# Filtered list not updated on pagination

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

- Ember      : 1.1.2
- Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.4+canary.c15b8f80
- Handlebars : 1.0.0
- jQuery     : 1.10.2

I have a list of objects that I can filter on a certain attribute value, e.g. all posts vs. published posts only.
I also created 2 routes, so both lists can be accessed using an url:

```
App.Router.map ->
  @resource 'posts', ->    # '/posts'
    @route 'published'     # '/posts/published'
```

Both lists use the same template:

```
App.PostsRoute = Em.Route.extend
  model: ->
    @get('store').find 'post'

App.PostsIndexRoute = Em.Route.extend
  model: ->
    @modelFor 'posts'

App.PostsPublishedRoute = Em.Route.extend
  model: ->
    @modelFor('posts').filter( (item) ->
      item.get('publishAt') <= new Date()
    )
  renderTemplate: (controller) ->
    @render 'posts/index',
      controller: controller

# posts.hbs
  ...
  {{#link-to 'posts.index'}}All{{/link-to}}
  {{#link-to 'posts.published'}}Published{{/link-to}}

  {{outlet}}

# posts/index.hbs
  {{#each}}
    <li>...</li>
  {{/each}}

  {{link-to showMore}}Show More{{/link-to}}
```

The `showMore` action in a base controller sends a request to a (Rails) backend which responds with the next page.

```
App.PostsController = Em.ArrayController.extend
  actions:
    showMore: ->
      @store.find 'post',
        page: 2
```

This `showMore` works as expected when the un-filtered list is shown. To keep the example simple, I hard-coded the page value.

However, when the filtered list is displayed, the `showMore` does send a AJAX request, but the page does not get updated with the extended list of objects. When I toggle between `All` and `Published` the list of published *is* updated.

Answer (score 0):

When the `showMore` action is called, the AJAX request is sent, but the list isn't updated. This is due to the fact that the route's `model` hook is called only on entering the route.

You need to make sure the list is updated when the posts change by filtering the collection in the `App.PostPublishedController`:

```
App.PostPublishedController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  needs: ['posts']
  posts: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.posts.content')

  content: ( ->
    @get('posts').filter( (item) ->
      item.get('publishAt') <= new Date()
    )
  ).property('posts.[]')
```

#### However what I would do is map the pages in the router scheme:

```
App.Router.map ->
  @resource 'firstPostsPage', { path: '/posts' }
  @resource 'posts', { path: '/posts/:page' }, ->
    @route 'published'

App.PostsRoute = Em.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    @get('store').find 'post',
      page: params.page

App.FirstPostsPageRoute = Em.Route.extend
  redirect: ->
   // Redirect '/posts' to '/posts/1'
   this.transitionTo('posts', { page: 1 });
```

Then the following routes definitions would work as expected, without the need to filter in `PostPublishedController`

```
App.PostsIndexRoute = Em.Route.extend
  model: ->
    @modelFor 'posts'

App.PostsPublishedRoute = Em.Route.extend
  model: ->
    @modelFor('posts').filter( (item) ->
      item.get('publishAt') <= new Date()
    )
  renderTemplate: (controller) ->
    @render 'posts/index',
      controller: controller
```

Comment: Thanks Panagiotis. I do understand your answer and this works for me, however I can't explain why I need to set the content only for the `PostsPublishedController` and why the `PostsController` works as expected.
Mapping the pages in the router is a very elegant way, but will not work for me, since I want to extend my list with one page every time i.o. showing a different page each time.